# Z-index and nested positioned elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out why the z-index property won't work. According to the mdn docs, as long as they are positioned elements, with a z-index, it should work. I have 3 divs, each nested in each other. I am just trying to get the z-index to work, so I give the `.outer-div` a `z-index: 3` while giving the `.inner-div` a `z-index: 1`. According to the docs, the greater the z-index, the closer it is to the observer. Doesn't that mean the purple in the `.outer-div` should cover up the red div in `.inner-div`?

```css
.outer-div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: purple;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  border: 1px purple dotted;
}

.middle-div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px 
}

.inner-div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px 
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  
  <div class="middle-div">
    
    <div class="inner-div"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put a [mcve] in your question please. There's a button in the editor that allows you to embed a runnable example. We shouldn't have to visit a third party site to get a complete example of your issue, plus if that site is ever down, blocked, or just goes away, then your question will lose all value to future visitors.

Comment: Sure, thanks for pointing that out. Made the edit. @j08691

Comment: It would cover the red if they weren't nested. If you have a box and there is another box inside of that box, no matter how close you look at the outer box, you will always see the inner box. Continued reading on stacking context https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: The comments are on the right track, but that is not the whole of it. As you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/5pLeztcf/5/), a positioned child in a non-positioned container will disappear behind its parent if its z-index is -1. Not so with a positioned child in a positioned container.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this functionality, you should make some changes. By default, HTML behaviour is only the last(child) element will populate on top.
If you do like below, it will work :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>demo!</title>
    <style>
    .outer-div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: purple;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  border: 1px purple dotted;
}

.middle-div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px 
}

.inner-div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px 
}
.visual{
    opacity: 0.7;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <div id="example"></div> -->
<div class="outer-div">

        <div class="middle-div">

          <div class="inner-div"> </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="outer-div visual"></div>
      <div class="middle-div visual" style="top:-150px; z-index: 2;"></div>
      <div class="inner-div visual" style="top:-250px; z-index: 1;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope, I understood the problem and hope this would help